# NativeScript how to update dynamically the view?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am new to application development with NativeScript and I will try to describe the whole situation and hopefully you will help me again to find a solution.

I started implementing the bottom navigation (with 4 tabs: predictions, news ...) as a component, and also the Side Drawer (with 5 different sports).

From the Side Drawer the user can choose the sport and accordingly the colors of the whole view are changed and in the tab predictions for example I want to show predictions from the chosen sport.

Everything is working fine, unfortunately, the list () with the selected predictions is not getting updated, only the Label with the counter for the predictions.
I don't know how is the best way to achieve that.

This is the home.component.html, which is showing the information in each tab:

```
<ActionBar [class]="sport_class">
    <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu"
        (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"></NavigationButton>
    <ActionItem icon="res://menu" android:visibility="collapsed"
        (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()" ios.position="left">
    </ActionItem>
    <Image [src]="logoSrc" class="logo"></Image>
</ActionBar>
<BottomNavigation selectedIndex="0">
    <TabStrip [class]="sport_class">
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Predictions"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf1e3;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Bookmakers"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf66f;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Bonuses"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf0a3;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="News"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf518;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <Label [text]="'Predictions ' + sport_class + ', count: ' + predictions.length"></Label>
            <ns-predictions></ns-predictions>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <ns-bookmakers></ns-bookmakers>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <ns-bonuses></ns-bonuses>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <ns-news></ns-news>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
</BottomNavigation>
```

Here is the home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { getString, setString } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";
import { PredictionsService } from '../predictions/predictions.service';
import { Prediction } from '../predictions/predictions.model';

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./home.component.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    predictions: Prediction[];
    public isLoading = false;
    public listLoaded = false;
    public sport_class: string;
    private logoSrc: string;

    constructor(private predictionService: PredictionsService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
            params => {
                this.sport_class = params.get('sport');
                this.logoSrc = getString('logo');
                this.loadPredictions();
            }
        )
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.loadPredictions();
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.listLoaded = true;
    }

    private async loadPredictions() {

        let date = '2020-05-19';
        return this.predictionService.getItems(date, this.sport_class).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
            this.predictions = data;
        });

    }

    onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }
}
```

here is the predictions.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PredictionsService } from './predictions.service';
import { Prediction } from './predictions.model';
import {
    getBoolean,
    getNumber,
    getString,
} from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";

var utilityModule = require("utils/utils");

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ns-predictions',
    templateUrl: './predictions.component.html',
    styleUrls: ["./predictions.component.css"]
})

export class PredictionsComponent implements OnInit {

    predictions: Prediction[];
    public isLoading = false;
    public listLoaded = false;

    constructor(private predictionService: PredictionsService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.loadPredictions();
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.listLoaded = true;
    }

    private async loadPredictions() {

        let date = '2020-05-19';
        return this.predictionService.getItems(date, getString('sport')).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
            console.log('I am here');
            this.predictions = data;
        });

    }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { DrawerTransitionBase, RadSideDrawer, SlideInOnTopTransition } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { getString, setString } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private _activatedUrl: string;
    private _sideDrawerTransition: DrawerTransitionBase;
    public sport_class: string;
    public logoSrc: string;

    constructor(private router: Router, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions, private store: Store) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject services.
        this.setSport('tennis');
        this.logoSrc = getString('logo');
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._activatedUrl = "/predictions/tennis";
        this._sideDrawerTransition = new SlideInOnTopTransition();

        this.router.events
            .pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
            .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => this._activatedUrl = event.urlAfterRedirects);
    }

    get sideDrawerTransition(): DrawerTransitionBase {
        return this._sideDrawerTransition;
    }

    onSportTap(sport: string) {
        this.setSport(sport);
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['predictions/' + sport], {
            transition: {
                name: "fade"
            }
        });

        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.closeDrawer();
    }

    isComponentSelected(url: string): boolean {
        return this._activatedUrl === url;
    }

    onNavItemTap(navItemRoute: string): void {
        this.routerExtensions.navigate([navItemRoute], {
            transition: {
                name: "fade"
            }
        });

        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.closeDrawer();
    }

    setSport(sport: string) {
        this.sport_class = sport;
        setString("sport", sport);
        this.logoSrc = this.getLogoPath(getString('sport'));
        setString("logo", this.getLogoPath(sport));
    }

    getLogoPath(sport: string) {
        return  sport + '/logo.png';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the drawer implementation, but u are not passing the data to NS-predictions component so the list will never update, u need to react on sport selection, then load the data of the current sport and then pass that data to the NS-predictions component using an input, also u can use libraries like Ngxs to centralize those information inside states then inside ur NS-predictions component u only need to subscribe the value inside the state to get the changes https://www.ngxs.io/

This is an example how u can solve the problem using a state management library like NGXS

- From the drawer  dispatch an action on sport selection passing as parameter the sport or sportId
  this.store.dispatch(new SelectSport(sport))
- Then let's say u have a Sports state with the following properties
  SelectedSport
  Sports
  Etc
- Also a PredictionsState
  IsLoading
  Predictions
  Etc
- When the event SelectSport is dispatched u can listen that inside predictions component and then dispatch another action like Load predictions passing that selected sport, inside ur predictions state u can call the service to load the predictions and update ur state with ur predictions
- Finally inside predictions component u need to select a part of ur predictions state in this case the predictions property and pass that to ur list.

Probably it can be a better way to organize the communication of the states but that's what I just came up with, I hope this can help u

U can find all the information of how to do what I described in the link I left you

Comment: I have added the app.component.ts where are the functions for the Side Drawer. As I understand I need to add in the onSportTab() function the following code: this.store.dispatch(new SelectSport(sport)) but here I don't understand what is SelectSport and in which file to define it? Once you tell me that, in it I will set the initial properties (sport, predictions, etc.) and in predictions.component.ts I need to listen for the changes. In which method should I listen? and what is the function to listen for the changes? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's why I let u the link of the library, Selects port is an Action basically is just an object with específico properties, the how to liste that action u can't find that information inside the guides provided in ngxs recipes or advanced examples, you can search about reacting to actions or listen action dispatched

Comment: @Component({ ... })
export class CartComponent {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(CartDelete)).subscribe(() => alert('Item deleted'));
  }
}

Comment: This is the link where u can find information about action handlers https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/action-handlers